# Why is document.getElementById("element_id") returning the HTML input tag it is contained in?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, getelementbyid

I'm trying to get input from an input field. Such that when the user clicks a button, a JS function is called and the user input is used therein.

This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- contents of head here -->
        <script src="./src/main.js" type="module"></script> />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <form id="form">
                <input type="text" id="search" class="search" placeholder="Search TMDB" required>
                <input type="button" id="search_btn"" class="search_btn" value="Search"/>
            </form>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>

<!-- written by invalidrishav -->
```

The `main.js` mentioned in the `script` tag is as follows:

```
// other imports here
import { key } from './Api.js';

// other functions here

function search() {
    var input = document.getElementById("search_btn");
    console.log(input);
    window.open(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${key}&query=${input}`,
        "TMDB", "menubar=1,resizable=1,width=500,height=500");
}
```

But when I click the `search_btn` button, this is what I get in console:

```
<input type="button" id="search_btn"" class="search_btn" value="Search" >
```

Also, it is not throwing any error in the console.
How do I take the value of the user input?

Comment: Thats exactly what  `document.getElementById` is suppose to do?

Comment: But how do I take the value of the user input?

Comment: `document.getElementById('foo').value`

Comment: As @DanielBeck mentioned, but in your example the 'input''s id is `search`, so it becomes `document.getElementById('search').value`

Comment: Worth a read: [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: yeah, I probably shouldn't have assumed the meaning of 'foo' was obvious; thanks @0stone0!